# Tooling for setting up continuous delivery for ASP .net MVC website with Java based backend on VMWare

Tags: vmware, release-management, continuous-deployment, mdt, dsc

I'm looking to change deployment into DevOps (continuous delivery).

I get different technologies from Devs and Ops in the organization:

- (Ops) Microsoft Deployment Toolkit
- (Dev) Desired State Configuration
- (Dev) Release Management for TFS

Which of these technologies work well together?
Does anybody have experience setting up continuous delivery for ASP .net MVC website with Java based backend on VMWare?
Can we keep on using TeamCity as Build Server?

Kind regards,
AllWorkNoPlay

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CloudMunch for this. CloudMunch supports Microsoft stack, VMWare, and Java stacks as well.

*Disclaimer: I work at CloudMunch*